# Why Cassandra upserts some rows with unique primary key during multiple insertion?

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

This is the entity class for which the table would be created on cassandra database.

```
@Table
public class Log {
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private LocalDate date; //partition key
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String name; //partition key
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 2, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String catagory; //partition key
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 3, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private String timeStamp; //clustering column
    private String type;
    private String description;
}
```

The primary key is ((date,name,category),timestamp) where (date,name,category) is partition key and timestamp is clustering column.

This is the expected data when insertion would be performed

```
   Date     |  name | category|     timestamp  |  type   | description |
------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.732  |  short  |  desc1 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.735  |  long   |  desc2 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.736  |  short  |  desc3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.738  |  long   |  desc4 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.740  |  short  |  desc5 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.741  |  short  |  desc6 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.743  |  long   |  desc7 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.745  |  short  |  desc8 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below data is stored in Cassandra when insertion is performed using CrudRepository's save method. Some rows are upserted. The rows with description desc3, desc5 are missing.

```
   Date     |  name | category|     timestamp  |  type   | description |
------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.732  |  short  |  desc1 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.735  |  long   |  desc2 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.738  |  long   |  desc4 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.741  |  short  |  desc6 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.743  |  long   |  desc7 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-11  |  201  | General |  19:51:18.745  |  short  |  desc8 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Repo being used is an interface which extends CrudRepository as follows:

```
public interface LogRepo extends CrudRepository<Log , LocalDate>
{
  ...
}
```

Insertion code performed is as follows:

```
for(...){
    ..
    logRepo.save(log); //each object is saved
    ..
}
```

Since clustering column is timestamp and is unique in this case, ideally the rows should not have been upserted. Please let know if there are anything that is missing to avoid upserting of records.

Comment: What is the consistency used in the program while querying? My guess is, the data is there but it was queried with consistency ONE and hence some data appears to be missing. Try to insert and read back with "local_quorum" consistency and let us know if you are able to reproduce.

Comment: Though consistency was changed to LOCAL_QUORUM from ONE, we are not able to get the same number of records that were inserted. Still some records are missing.